# What is the "CC" and "Numero" of a credit card holder in Colombia?

Tags: payment-cards, colombia

I'm trying to make a purchase from Mercadolibre, and am presented with this puzzling "TIPO" and "Numero".

[image: Mercado Libre credit card purchase dialog]

After pondering how many customers they lose daily because of this poorly-conceived credit card purchase dialog, I wonder what those fields mean.

Comment: https://brainly.lat/tarea/6208763 suggests that they are different types of ID documents.  If you live in Colombia, presumably you know what they are.  If you don't, you probably don't have any of those numbers and therefore can't use this form.  Maybe they are only selling to Colombian residents, or else they want foreigners to make the purchase some other way. Did you have an option to select country of residence at any point?

Comment: @NateEldredge: nope. I could only select the delivery address, then my name an an unspecified ID number (how they would validate that, beats me).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently "Tipo" is the [Identification Document Type](https://brainly.lat/tarea/6208763):

- C.C: Cedula de Ciudadania
- C.E: Cédula de Extranjería
- N.I.T: Numero de Identificacion Tributaria

The "Cedula de Extranjeria [is](https://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish-to-english/finance-general/3437347-cc-and-ce-colombian-spanish.html) is apparently given to visitors who are staying over 3 months, so as a regular tourist, I can't enter any meaningful data in that field.

After entering "1234...", I was forced to register a Colombian phone number (which I don't have, given the ridiculous registration required to get one, when I already use Google Fi), so Mercadolibre lost another customer.

[image: Mercadolibre forces SMS validation with Colombian number]

(the '+57' is not changeable)

**UPDATE**: I used a friend's Colombia number. Now Mercadolibre wants a PHOTO OF MY CEDULA. They can sod off :)

[image: Mercadolibre stupidity]

Comment: Are you able to replace +57 in the phone number with your country code? I've experienced a number of websites that fill their country code for you but I was able to delete it and put mine in.

Comment: @kiradotee: no; that was the first thing I tried. It's not a drop-down or an editable field.

Answer (score 2):

*** Update a few days later, I sent a message on their chat explaining my situation and they accepted my payment.  Seems that although they are set up for S.America, they can process foreign cards if you explain.
MY INITIAL POST ~
Strangely i was in Colombia Feb 2020 and ordered something from these guys to be delivered to my hotel and had no problems. Now, trying the same from Melbourne, I have your problem. I managed to get through that only to find I needed some document of change and the Mercado Libre is only Libre for Colombians, they only accept local accounts.
So like you it's a sod off.
I'll order from Amazon and post it myself !